# What Permissions Are Used For Scripts On Startup?

Tags: permissions, cron

If I create a rc.local job to execute a script @reboot. I am wondering at what point in the startup the script is executed, and what permission level the the job executes my script at? I have a feeling it would be called upon user login & assign owner permissions to execute my script. But I would like someone to confirm it.

Comment: The question is unlear. `rc.local` runs as root, cron too. You can run as a user too. Cron is not for running at startup.

Comment: Yeah rc.local, thats what I mean. Sorry I will mod the question. So it runs as root? OK. I will modify the permissions of my file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rc.local` script runs as `root`.